# Can Lenovo Yoga 13 power 2 HDMI monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, lenovo-laptop

I'm considering getting a Lenovo Yoga 13
I see the processor is a 3rd Generation Intel Core i7-3537U Processor( 2.00GHz 1600MHz 4MB)
http://shop.lenovo.com/GB/en/laptops/ideapad/yoga/yoga-13/?&cid=uk|semd|se|google|lenovoukdirect|z20EDC|s

When I look up the Intel link 
http://ark.intel.com/products/72054/ it says # of Displays Supported    3

However there only seems to be one output port.
I want to avoid using USB converters or anything like that, I just want to power 2 HDMI monitors.

Some advise would really help.

Answer (score 1):

If the laptop chasis/motherboard offers only one HDMI port, then only one device can be connected. It does not matter how many monitors the internal chip supports.

Comment: He could use an HDMI splitter.

Comment: @Krugg An HDMI splitter will always mirror the display, its not really using the multi-display capability of the graphics chip.

Comment: Adding the following from Intel: `This feature may not be available on all computing systems. Please check with the system vendor to determine if your system delivers this feature, or reference the system specifications (motherboard, processor, chipset, power supply, HDD, graphics controller, memory, BIOS, drivers, virtual machine monitor-VMM, platform software, and/or operating system) for feature compatibility. Functionality, performance, and other benefits of this feature may vary depending on system configuration.` Although the processor is able to handle it, the mobo just doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0):

HDMI 2.0 and above supports Dual View (two signals in a single HDMI cable from a single port). Yoga 13 does not seem to have an HDMI 2.0 port, so it will not support dual monitors, even though the Intel HD Graphics 4000 supports them. To be sure, you should contact Lenovo technical support with your laptops UPC and ask them directly. An expensive solution is to buy an HDMI 2.0 cable, a splitter and an extra monitor and just give it a shot :)

Answer (score 0):

Only way is to add a hd-usb adapter, however nothing wrong with that. They work great we are on about our sixth configuration